# Error being thrown on reconnection after disconnection in node-redis client

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, runtime-error, node-redis

I couldn't understand what's the reason for the `SocketClosedUnexpectedlyError` error fired in the code below:

```
const redisClient = require('redis').createClient();

redisClient.connect().then(function() {
  return redisClient.disconnect();
})
.then(function() {
  redisClient.connect();
});
```

If I wrap the second `redisClient.connect()` call inside a `setTimeout()` call, as shown below, the error seems to go away:

```
const redisClient = require('redis').createClient();

redisClient.connect().then(function() {
  return redisClient.disconnect();
})
.then(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    redisClient.connect();
  }, 0);
});
```

Can anyone please explain what's the reason for the error thrown above? The documentation of [`@node-redis`](https://github.com/redis/node-redis/) isn't good enough to explain this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in node-redis v4...

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/issues/1801

https://github.com/redis/node-redis/commit/74daee302338cf2fcc1bb48aeac02be828e0c6d7

Comment: So that was a bug and I think that you have corrected it. Isn't that it? Anyways thanks...

Comment: Should I reinstall node-redis using npm to rectify this issue?

Comment: @coderboy it'll be released next week with version 4.0.2, until then you can use `queueMicrotask`/`setTimeout` to workaround that

Comment: I'm still getting this error even on `v4.0.4`. How exactly can we use `queueMicrotask`/`setTimeout` as a workaround @LeibaleEidelman?

Comment: Wait just realised that typeorm (what I'm using redis cache via) has a peer dependency of `"redis": "^3.1.1"`, so its not up to date. So yh same question @LeibaleEidelman how can I use `queueMicrotask`/`setTimeout` as a workaround? Thanks